# Shortest Path Data Structure

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I'm trying to come up with a shortest path algorithm, using the Greedy Tree algorithm.
Examples: Dijkstra or Prim
I however can't seem to figure out how I should be making my data structure.

When I tried to create a data structure, all i could do was ending up with a one-way solution for like A to F.. But you would be unable to go from F to A..

Now I'm wondering, could someone give me an example code (Java prefered) how to set such a structure?

My latest attempt:

```
public class Point {
    //public List<Point> connections = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public List<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    public List<Point> connectedWith = new ArrayList<Point>();
    public char name;

    public Point(char name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    /*public Point getConnectionByIndex(int index) {
        return this.connections.get(index);
    }*/
}
```

and

```
public class Connection {
    private Point nameFirst, nameSecond;
    private int connectionLength;

    public Connection(Point nameFirst, Point nameSecond, int connectionLength) {
        this.setNameFirst(nameFirst);
        this.setNameSecond(nameSecond);
        this.connectionLength = connectionLength;
    }

    public int getConnectionLength() {
        return connectionLength;
    }

    public void setConnectionLength(int connectionLength) {
        this.connectionLength = connectionLength;
    }

    public Point getNameSecond() {
        return nameSecond;
    }

    public void setNameSecond(Point nameSecond) {
        this.nameSecond = nameSecond;
    }

    public Point getNameFirst() {
        return nameFirst;
    }

    public void setNameFirst(Point nameFirst) {
        this.nameFirst = nameFirst;
    }

}
```

Kind Regards,
Larssy1

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: you want a data structure to store which edges are connection to which vertices, for a directed graph?

Comment: well.. i'm trying to find a way to connect every vertice. Where every connection has a 'weight'.. not sure it its directed or not..

Comment: `all i could do was ending up with a one-way solution for like A to F.. But you would be unable to go from F to A..`

this generally means it is directed..

Comment: "In computer science, Prim's algorithm is a greedy algorithm that finds a minimum spanning tree for a connected weighted undirected graph.".. It might just be that ive done it wrong.. :x but wouldn't change the fact that i wouldn't know how to solve it..

Comment: see, if the graph is undirected. the path from A to F ( that you found ) will be the same path that would be taken for going from F to A.

Comment: Ya it should.. but sadly im unable to find a way to do that.. as everything is connected in one way.. which means.. A would for example have 2 connected vertices.. but F (the last one in line) would have 0, as they are connected to him, not the way around.

Comment: have you tried storing the edges and their values in an adjacency list (for undirected graphs) or adjacency matrix ( for directed graphs)?

Comment: I uhm, never heard of that i think.. do you happen to have an example? ;x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62064/discussion-between-ralph-and-larssy1).